# Use google sheet as an automatic calculator for another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Recently I've been working a lot on using google sheet. As a question occurs to me, is it possible to input some numbers on A sheet, the B sheet will take the input from A sheet and do the desired calculations, after a few moments, the result will appear on the A sheet. All the user has to do is to input some numbers on A sheet and link to B sheet, likewise for any other sheets that want to use B as a calculator.

For example, I have two test sheets and a calculator

Test1
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lJmlYYYCR2Zs4CKNFMyprFyCk6eRKTBqMPF3a_IjguY/edit#gid=0

Test2
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/118sP9jz8LXsLcbUAcMls9Movrl_bb4fYhx31Na-XrTs/edit#gid=0

Calculator
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FHpbUHEMlZ2f-SrrJakZCOdqhjKDUP-a3STUtwWKBzA/edit#gid=0

The only way I can think of is use vlookup to get the results from the calculator while the calculator use importrange to get the input from Test1 and Test2. However, the problem for this method is that I need to when I have many test sheets, I have to do importrange every time a new test sheet uses the calculator. What I want is that is there any way that I don't have to change the calculator sheet and in such everyone can use the calculator without looking into what the calculator is doing or add the test sheet link manually?

Comment: Why not you calculate on test sheet instead of separate calculator?

Comment: @Harun24hr Because the calculation in my real case is far more complicated than the above example, it couldn't be done using a single formula.

Comment: @james2335 have you considered creating a [Named Function](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/named-functions/)? That way you don’t have to deal with the separate test sheets. Even without names functions you could also have your calculations done in a different tab within the spreadsheet to avoid importing ranges.

Comment: `Because the calculation in my real case is far more complicated than the above example` There are many ways that your question might be resolved BUT they may not be appropriate for the specific calculation that you are trying to do. Far better that you describe the calculation, describe where/how the user would input these numbers, the frequency of calculation, etc, describe where/how the result would appear. The reason for doing this is that any answer is going to address your specific conditions not a simplified/simplistic approximation.